# Mean for every column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

How,can I get the mean of each column, each column contain multiple value, and there are 1000 of column. I don't want to use loop for efficiency reason.
I have tried colmeans, rowmeans.

data format= each col with all rows is a dataframe and all these dataframes are saved in a list

```
For example data look like 
list_of_df=        
    col1                     col2         .........coln
 v1 c(10,11,12....)     c(12,11,9....)              c(12,11,9....)
 v2 c(1,1,1,1,1,1...)   c(1,1,1,1,1,1...)           c(1,1,1,1,1,1...)
 v3 c(0 ,0,1,2,3,..)    c(0 ,0,2,2,2,3,..)          c(0 ,0,2,2,2,3,..)
 v4 c(date1,dat2,....)  c(date1,dat2,....)          c(date1,dat2,....)
```

I want to calculate the mean for V1 row for every column.

Thanks

Comment: The structure of this data is not a matrix. Please use `dput` to output the data and copy the output into your question.

Comment: That seems like quite an odd way of storing data. Looks like you'd be better with a 3-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, the solution for my problem is

```
meanValue=sapply(list_of_df[1,1:ncol(list_of_df)], function(x) mean(x))
```

Comment: you shouldn't need `function(x) mean(x)` ... `mean` should suffice

Comment: yes you are right, thanks for the information.I need to ask also one more thing if you have time can you guide me how can i proceed in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971669/when-the-column-in-a-dataframe-changes-the-value-and-save-all-the-rows-between-t?noredirect=1#comment65298320_38971669

Answer (score 0):

Try colMeans(YourDataStructure[1,]).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a method without having a `dput` of your data structure to work from. But based on your description you could try:

```
MeanResults <-
   lapply(list_of_df,
      function(dat) {
        mean(dat["V1",])
      })
```

You can `unlist` this if you need it as a vectors.

You should consider if you can get you data in a better structure for manipulation, you'll save yourself time and effort in the long run :)

Comment: This solution did not work, yeah i will try to change  the structure, i am basically new to R, and i am getting this data as a result, from this problem, may be you will get better idea what i am doing then . I have a solution with loop but i dont want to use that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971669/when-the-column-in-a-dataframe-changes-the-value-and-save-all-the-rows-between-t?noredirect=1#comment65298320_38971669

Comment: I got the answer for the problem, i needed in vector so i applied sapply with the change.                meanValue=sapply(list_of_df[1,1:ncol(list_of_df)], function(x) mean(x))